# Extjs 3.4 ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME when calling valid json url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, extjs

Using Extjs 3.4. I have a simple ajax request:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "localhost:3000/offers.json",  
    success: function(response, opts) {
      var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
      console.dir(obj);
   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
   }
});
```

The localhost:3000/offers.json is a Rails 4 back-end and it works fine:

```
$curl localhost:3000/offers.json              
[{"id":1,"desc":"a description","img_link":"www.google.come","product_link":"www.google.come","code":"927341","price":"20.29","special_price":"13.99","saving":"31.0","created_at":"2014-06-23T15:45:11.404Z","updated_at":"2014-06-23T15:45:11.404Z"}]
```

So the back-end si working.

When i call the json url from my `Ext.Ajax.request` I have this error in Chrome console:

```
OPTIONS localhost:3000/offers.json net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME ext-base.js:21
i ext-base.js:21
Ext.lib.Ajax.k.request ext-base.js:21
Ext.extend.request ext-all-debug.js:4636
ajaxSearch_function grid-ajax.js:8
Ext.Button.Ext.extend.onClick ext-all-debug.js:31872
h ext-all-debug.js:5215
server-side failure with status code 0
```

Ideas?

Comment: TRY `url: "http://localhost:3000/offers.json"`

Comment: I havve just try but now I have an other error:OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/offers.json 404 (Not Found) ext-base.js:21
i ext-base.js:21
Ext.lib.Ajax.k.request ext-base.js:21
Ext.extend.request ext-all-debug.js:4636
ajaxSearch_function grid-ajax.js:8
Ext.Button.Ext.extend.onClick ext-all-debug.js:31872
h ext-all-debug.js:5215
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/offers.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. index.html:1
server-side failure with status code 0 grid-ajax.js:16

Comment: check `localhost:3000/offers.json` directly in browser and make sure it returns as expexted

Comment: In browser It works fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w

Comment: it is cross origin request error

Comment: I'm working on my local machine..

Comment: what is the url you using for testing? it it starts with "localhost:3000" ar other port?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/offers.json works well

Comment: you nedd to use jsonp

Comment: I have moved my extjs files from local folder to localhost web server. Is not a final solution but now it works

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a cross domain call from Ajax  , Ajax wont support it.

You have to use JsonP.It is useful when you want to load data from other domain .

Once check this example and try to implement the same in your code.

```
http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.1/docs/Ext.data.JsonP.1/viewer.html
```

Hope this helps..